# Obout grid OnClientCallbackError not showing alert message

Tags: javascript, c#-4.0

I am using an Obout grid in my application. I have set the client side events on it and all the  other client side events work perfectly except:OnClientCallbackError.I have a method on the serverside that validates the delete on the database side before it can be executed. Here is the code for it:

```
protected void DeleteRecord(object sender, GridRecordEventArgs e)
        {
            //check if the record is not used in any other relationship
            var id = Convert.ToInt32(e.Record["ID"].ToString());
            var result =_areaRepository.RelationshipCheck("env_Area", id);
            var desc = e.Record["Description"].ToString();
        string message;
            if(result <= 0)
            {
                //show error message
                _areaRepository.UpdateArea(id, desc, true);
               }
            else
            {
                message = "Record cannot be  deleted";
               throw new Exception(message);
            }
        }
```

This is a delete on a lookup table, what the above code does is to check if the record being deleted has not been used in any other relationship. if its not been used then we have a field called DLTD that we update to true to make sure that the user never sees this record again. This part works.

If the record has been used in a relationship  an exception message is thrown.
Now based on the examples on the Obout site:

if you have a function that looks like the one below:

```
function onCallbackError(errorMessage, commandType, recordIndex, data) {
        alert(errorMessage);
        callbackErrorWasRaised = true;
    }
```

and on your clientside events of the grid you have:

```
<ClientSideEvents ExposeSender="True" OnClientAdd="OnAdd" OnClientEdit="OnEdit" OnClientCallbackError="onCallbackError" />
```

the alert message must be displayed with no problems, but mine is not working.
I have removed the update panel from my code. And I have a script manager on my master page that looks like:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" ScriptMode="Release" EnablePageMethods="True" EnablePartialRendering="True">
  </asp:ScriptManager>
```

We have bought the Obout suite. I have asked the same question to the Obout support but they have not replied to me after a whole week. When I run the application I see that the error is thrown and my application crushes. The code for the grid is:

```
 <cc1:Grid ID="grid1" runat="server" CallbackMode="true" Serialize="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
    OnRebind="RebindGrid" OnInsertCommand="InsertRecord" OnDeleteCommand="DeleteRecord"
    OnUpdateCommand="UpdateRecord" EnableTypeValidation="False">
    <ClientSideEvents ExposeSender="True" OnClientAdd="OnAdd" OnClientEdit="OnEdit" OnClientCallbackError="onCallbackError" />

<TemplateSettings RowEditTemplateId="tplRowEdit" />
    <Columns>
        <cc1:Column DataField="ID" Visible="false" Width="150" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="ID">
        </cc1:Column>
        <cc1:Column DataField="Code" AllowGroupBy="true" Wrap="false" ShowFilterCriterias="true"
            ParseHTML="false" Align="left" HeaderAlign="left" Width="200" HeaderText="Code">
            <TemplateSettings RowEditTemplateControlId="txtCode" RowEditTemplateControlPropertyName="value" />
        </cc1:Column>
        <cc1:Column DataField="Description" Visible="True" AllowGroupBy="true" Wrap="false"
            ShowFilterCriterias="true" ParseHTML="false" Align="left" HeaderAlign="left"
            Width="250" HeaderText="Description">
            <TemplateSettings RowEditTemplateControlId="txtDescription" RowEditTemplateControlPropertyName="value" />
        </cc1:Column>
        <cc1:Column DataField="UnitMeasureID" Visible="true" ShowFilterCriterias="true" HeaderAlign="left"
            ParseHTML="false" Align="left" Width="190" HeaderText="UnitMeasureID">
            <TemplateSettings RowEditTemplateControlId="txtUnitMeasureID" RowEditTemplateControlPropertyName="value" />
        </cc1:Column>
        <cc1:Column DataField="DLTD" Visible="false" ShowFilterCriterias="true" HeaderAlign="left"
            ParseHTML="false" Align="left" Width="110" HeaderText="DLTD">
        </cc1:Column>
        <cc1:Column HeaderText="EDIT" Width="150" AllowEdit="true" AllowDelete="true" />
    </Columns>
 <Templates>
        <cc1:GridTemplate runat="server" ID="tplRowEdit">
            <Template>
                <table class="rowEditTable">
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top">
                            <fieldset style="width: 275px; height: 175px;">
                                <legend>New Mining Area Information</legend>
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            Code:
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="text" id="txtCode" style="width: 150px;" class="ob_gEC" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            Description:
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="text" id="txtDescription" style="width: 150px;" class="ob_gEC" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            Unit Measure:
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <cc3:OboutDropDownList ID="txtUnitMeasureID" runat="server" Height="150" Width="100%"
                                                DataSourceID="unitMeasureODS" DataTextField="Description" DataValueField="ID">
                                            </cc3:OboutDropDownList>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="2">
                                            <br />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </fieldset>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" align="center">
                            <input type="button" value="Save" onclick="grid1.save()" class="tdText" />
                            <input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="grid1.cancel()" class="tdText" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </Template>
        </cc1:GridTemplate>
    </Templates>
</cc1:Grid>
```

Comment: can you share html used to define obout grid with this event.

Comment: I have modified the question and added the code in there.